# What requirements does the standard impose on the Value type of unordered_set in terms of definition visibility

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, std

I'm creating a class that contains an `unordered_set` with its own hash and predicate as follows:

```
//SetHolder.h
#include <unordered_set>

struct SetHolder
{
    SetHolder(); //Defined in SetHolder.cpp
    ~SetHolder(); //Defined in SetHolder.cpp

    struct ArtifactImpl; //Defined in SetHolder.cpp
    struct ArtifactSetKeyOps
    {
      std::size_t operator()(
        const ArtifactImpl& artifact) const noexcept;
      bool operator()(
        const ArtifactImpl& lhs, const ArtifactImpl& rhs) const;
    };

    std::unordered_set<ArtifactImpl,
      ArtifactSetKeyOps,ArtifactSetKeyOps> artifactSet_;
};
```

I'm using the *gcc 4.8.2 compiler* under *ubuntu linux (stdlibc++)*, and I've observed that it compiles when only declaring `ArtifactImpl` if I only use `unordered_set` from the cpp file. Yet, I need to provide the definition of `ArtifactSetKeyOps` (why, I don't understand).

- What requirements does the standard impose on the **Value** type of
  `unordered_set` in terms of definition visibility at the time of
  declaring `unordered_set`?
- Is this code supposed to work on all platforms? Also, if so, why does
  the **Hash** and the **Predicate** need to be visible during the declaration
  of `unordered_set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_set` have no special requirements on their template parameters in this regard, so the general library-wide rule applies. Which is C++14 17.6.4.8/2.5:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> ...
>
> - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component,
>     unless specifically allowed for that component.

So if either the value type, hash type, or predicate type are incomplete (which is true in your case), you have Undefined Behaviour.

Since this bullet point specifically says "template *component"* while the rest of that clause refers to *functions,* I would say this means a class template is also a "template component." And in your case, the class template is instantiated at the definition of the `artifactSet_` member in the definition of the `SetHolder` class.

Comment: Angew, so when is the template component instantiated (or what is it's Point Of Instantiation(POI)? I'm assuming it's POI is where in this case SetHolder is defined/instantiated, and not where SetHolder's constructor is defined. Therefore this code has undefined behaviour?

Comment: @WernerErasmus Edited.